# How to fit my GUI app on small screens (netbooks)?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, gui-builder

I have problems with fitting my application on a netbook (1024x600).How could I solve it?

The GUI has been made with NetBeans GUI Builder.

So what I want is that the application scales automaticaly.

Regards.

Comment: how you construct your GUI? post some code, without that, I can say you only to use `LayoutManager`.

Comment: 1) usage of LayoutManager and properly, 2) component tree could be JFrame - JScrollPane - JPanel (there are placed JComponents)

Comment: I'm using Free Design as Layout.

Comment: Well, finally I had to manage adapting it manually, I didn't found any other solution.